# Azure, deleting group resurce error

Tags: azure, azure-cli

As stated in the azure support page, I'm writing on Stack Overflow to find a solution to my issue, but for me this looks a little bit off topic...

When I'm trying to delete a group resource via linux terminal I get:

```
Delete resource group Default-Storage-WestEurope? [y/n] y
+ Deleting resource group Default-Storage-WestEurope                           
error:   Long running operation failed with error: 'Invalid status code with response body "{"Error":{"Code":"ResourceGroupDeletionBlocked","Target":null,"Message":"Deletion of resource group 'Default-Storage-WestEurope' failed as resources with identifiers 'Microsoft.ClassicStorage/storageAccounts/bitnamiwesteuropecfuropu' could not be deleted. The provisioning state of the resource group will be rolled back. The tracking Id is 'f791a8f0-a28a-4fe3-b491-c6251b51d987'. Please check audit logs for more details.","Details":[{"Code":null,"Target":"/subscriptions/5fdcf34e-ecda-408e-b3ba-e706ac34dba6/resourceGroups/Default-Storage-WestEurope/providers/Microsoft.ClassicStorage/storageAccounts/bitnamiwesteuropecfuropu","Message":"{\"error\":{\"code\":\"StorageAccountOperationFailed\",\"message\":\"Unable to delete storage account 'bitnamiwesteuropecfuropu': 'Storage account bitnamiwesteuropecfuropu has some active image(s) and/or disk(s), e.g. bitnami-bitnami-redis-3.2.1-0-westeurope-CfuROpU. Ensure these image(s) and/or disk(s) are removed before deleting this storage account.'.\"}}","Details":null}]}}" occurred when polling for operation status.'.
info:    Error information has been recorded to /home/giumbai/.azure/azure.err
error:   group delete command failed
```

Edit: So I've made some progress, but still not enough. So i have a blob that has an image with an lease, in order to bake the lease i used this command: `azure storage blob lease break -a bitnamiwesteuropecfuropu -k <my key>` then i was prompted to insert the container name and blob name.

But didn't worked, i get this error, that i don't really understand:

```
{ ArgumentNullError: Required argument blob for function _leaseImpl is not defined
  <<< async stack >>>
    at throwMissingArgument (/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure-storage/lib/common/util/validate.js:417:9)
    at ArgumentValidator._.extend.exists (/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure-storage/lib/common/util/validate.js:447:7)
    at ArgumentValidator._.extend.string (/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure-storage/lib/common/util/validate.js:426:10)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure-storage/lib/services/blob/blobservice.js:4661:9
    at Object.validateArgs (/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure-storage/lib/common/util/validate.js:495:3)
    at Object.BlobService._leaseImpl (/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure-storage/lib/services/blob/blobservice.js:4660:14)
    at Object.BlobService.breakLease (/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure-storage/lib/services/blob/blobservice.js:1253:8)
    at Function.Object.defineProperty.value (/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/streamline/lib/callbacks/builtins.js:367:19)
    at __1 (/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/util/storage.util.js:423:41)
  at StorageUtil_performStorageOperation__1 (/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/util/storage.util.js:421:5)
  at StorageUtil_breakLease__10 (/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/util/storage.util.js:1609:31)
  at breakLease (/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/commands/storage/storage.blob.js:817:17)
  at breakBlobLease (/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/commands/storage/storage.blob.js:802:5)
  <<< raw stack >>>
    at throwMissingArgument (/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure-storage/lib/common/util/validate.js:417:9)
    at ArgumentValidator._.extend.exists (/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure-storage/lib/common/util/validate.js:447:7)
    at ArgumentValidator._.extend.string (/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure-storage/lib/common/util/validate.js:426:10)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure-storage/lib/services/blob/blobservice.js:4661:9
    at Object.validateArgs (/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure-storage/lib/common/util/validate.js:495:3)
    at Object.BlobService._leaseImpl (/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure-storage/lib/services/blob/blobservice.js:4660:14)
    at Object.BlobService.breakLease (/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure-storage/lib/services/blob/blobservice.js:1253:8)
    at Function.Object.defineProperty.value (/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/streamline/lib/callbacks/builtins.js:367:19)
    at __$__1 (/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/util/storage.util.js:423:41)
    at __func (/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/streamline/lib/callbacks/runtime.js:47:5)
  stack: [Getter/Setter],
  name: 'ArgumentNullError',
  argumentName: 'blob',
  message: 'Required argument blob for function _leaseImpl is not defined',
  __frame: 
   { name: 'StorageUtil_performStorageOperation__1',
     line: 402,
     file: '/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/util/storage.util.js',
     prev: 
      { name: 'StorageUtil_breakLease__10',
        line: 1598,
        file: '/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/util/storage.util.js',
        prev: [Object],
        calls: 3,
        active: false,
        offset: 11,
        col: 30 },
     calls: 1,
     active: false,
     offset: 19,
     col: 4 },
  rawStack: [Getter] }
ArgumentNullError: Required argument blob for function _leaseImpl is not defined
  <<< async stack >>>
    at throwMissingArgument (/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure-storage/lib/common/util/validate.js:417:9)
    at ArgumentValidator._.extend.exists (/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure-storage/lib/common/util/validate.js:447:7)
    at ArgumentValidator._.extend.string (/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure-storage/lib/common/util/validate.js:426:10)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure-storage/lib/services/blob/blobservice.js:4661:9
    at Object.validateArgs (/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure-storage/lib/common/util/validate.js:495:3)
    at Object.BlobService._leaseImpl (/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure-storage/lib/services/blob/blobservice.js:4660:14)
    at Object.BlobService.breakLease (/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure-storage/lib/services/blob/blobservice.js:1253:8)
    at Function.Object.defineProperty.value (/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/streamline/lib/callbacks/builtins.js:367:19)
    at __1 (/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/util/storage.util.js:423:41)
  at StorageUtil_performStorageOperation__1 (/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/util/storage.util.js:421:5)
  at StorageUtil_breakLease__10 (/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/util/storage.util.js:1609:31)
  at breakLease (/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/commands/storage/storage.blob.js:817:17)
  at breakBlobLease (/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/commands/storage/storage.blob.js:802:5)
  <<< raw stack >>>
    at throwMissingArgument (/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure-storage/lib/common/util/validate.js:417:9)
    at ArgumentValidator._.extend.exists (/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure-storage/lib/common/util/validate.js:447:7)
    at ArgumentValidator._.extend.string (/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure-storage/lib/common/util/validate.js:426:10)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure-storage/lib/services/blob/blobservice.js:4661:9
    at Object.validateArgs (/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure-storage/lib/common/util/validate.js:495:3)
    at Object.BlobService._leaseImpl (/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure-storage/lib/services/blob/blobservice.js:4660:14)
    at Object.BlobService.breakLease (/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/azure-storage/lib/services/blob/blobservice.js:1253:8)
    at Function.Object.defineProperty.value (/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/streamline/lib/callbacks/builtins.js:367:19)
    at __$__1 (/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/lib/util/storage.util.js:423:41)
    at __func (/usr/lib/node_modules/azure-cli/node_modules/streamline/lib/callbacks/runtime.js:47:5)
```

Edit2: Interesting i managed to delete the remaining image i had to brake the lease on the image and on the container, so both the image and container are now deleted, but when i try to delete the empty storage i get:

```
Failed to delete storage account 'bitnamiwesteuropecfuropu'. Unable to delete storage account 'bitnamiwesteuropecfuropu': 'Storage account bitnamiwesteuropecfuropu has some active image(s) and/or disk(s), e.g. bitnami-bitnami-redis-3.2.1-0-westeurope-CfuROpU. Ensure these image(s) and/or disk(s) are removed before deleting this storage account.'.
```

[Proof](https://s31.postimg.org/sv69noqa3/Screenshot_2016_07_12_17_26_38.png) :)

```
Successfully deleted blob 'bitnami-images/bitnami-bitnami-redis-3.2.1-0-westeurope-CfuROpU'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not threat to leave the service for ever this will not get your answers any faster. If you read the error message it is pretty clear on that what it is happening. You are trying to delete a storage account that has a disk that it is attached to a machine. You cannot delete a storage account with a disk that is with a running machine. Go to the portal and check the storage account you will find that the storage account has a file inside it. If you click on this vcs file you are going to see that the state of this file it is locked and the lease has infinity duration. Checking on your account you até going to find a machine that has a disk file on this storage account. Delete the virtual machine and delete the storage account after the lease will be released when you delete the storage account.

Comment: nope, there is no other VM, there is no other resource group, there is just a container... this is a bug.

Comment: and also, I'm not threatening, I'm just stating what are my solutions...

Comment: A cpntainer can pick the disk the same way can you check on the portal if the file it is locked? If it is you need to remove the lock deleting what it is using it would release the lock

Comment: believe me, for the past day this is what i've been trying, i deleted  everything that i could from the both portals, new and old, i also verified  from the terminal everything, because obviously this is azure and what you see in the terminal doesn't means that you can also see in the portal. And there is nothing left, just the storage container that can't be deleted. And also with `group delete` i've deleted everything from CDN, DNS, VM, Storages and so on with no problem. This is a bug related to how bitnami creates VM in azure.

Comment: If it is a bug you can open a ticket for free on the help

Comment: Don't you have anything on your subscription aside of your current storage account? Can you see anything inside the container?